# Where does diffmerge store its temp files

Tags: rhapsody, diffmerge

I recently started to work with IBM Rhapsody and I try to personalize it, but in order to do that I got to have a better understanding of DiffMerge.

What I want to do is this: I have two diagrams, I load them in DiffMerge and it shows me a lot of differences, from the bigger component to the smaller one, highlighting it. I want to get rid of the highlight of the bigger component, and I believe I can do that by using the Rhapsody Java API, but for that I will need the files that DiffMerge uses to display the differences, if those exists.

Until now I ran `Diffmerge.exe -compare <file1> <file2> ‑diffReport <filename>` which will give me a difference report, it's readable, but I hoped that I will find something more detailed and I hope that if Diffmerge had some temporary files filled with info I could actually make some progress.

Did someone do this until now? Do You know if it is possible?

Thanks again for your patience,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I ended up noticing that DiffMerge is using the report to compute the graphical difference